# Python: 'Refresh' specific variables within a script

Tags: python, variables, refresh, reload

Alrighty, so I have this python script that copies text from multiple files and pastes it to new files of a different file extension. It's almost done however I have a problem with its refresh button.

To use it, just put some files in the 'Input' directory, run the program and go.

In the event that the user runs the program with no files in the 'Input' folder, sees that the file count is zero and then puts some files in the folder, I want the file_count variable to be reloaded.

At the moment, I have a function called 'refresh()' that opens another instance of the program and then closes the initial instance. This works, but because 'os.startfile' is not designed for this use, it has a few problems:

Firstly ofcourse, it seems like overkill to relaunch the entire program.

Secondly, 'os.startfile' only works on windows.

Thirdly, if the window is moved and then the program is 'refreshed', the new instance will open in the default position.

So is there anyway to re run just the 'file_count' variable?

PS. I'm self taught so there are gaps in my knowledge (apparently, this is one of them.)
PPS. Just about to start a lecture, so I will only be able to reply in an hour.

```
import sys
import os, os.path
from os import listdir
import shutil
from Tkinter import *
from Tkinter import Tk
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename

path, dirs, files = os.walk(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'Input')).next()
file_count = len(files)
dirList = os.listdir(path)

def refresh():
    opencp = os.startfile(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'Copy_Paster.py'))
    closecp = os.execl(sys.executable, *([sys.executable]+sys.argv))

def copy_paste():
    # Copy pastes text from source documents to new ones.
    for fname in dirList:
      print fname
      extension = text_entered.get()
      copy = open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'Input', fname), "r")
      paste = open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'Output', fname + extension), "w+")
      copy.seek(0)
      shutil.copyfileobj(copy,paste)
      copy.close()
      paste.close()

# Window Geometry
width = "250"
height = "70"

# Window
root = Tk()
root.geometry(width+"x"+height+"+500+200",)
root.resizable(0,0)
root.title("Copy Paster")
text_entered = StringVar()

counter = Label(text="Input Directory: " + str(file_count) + " files.")
counter.place(x=int(width)-248,y=int(height)-63)

refresh = Button(root,command=refresh,text="Refresh")#Why this no work?
refresh.place(x=int(width)-80,y=int(height)-65, width=70)


format_label = Label(text="Output File Format:")
format_label.place(x=int(width)-248,y=int(height)-35)
document_type = Entry(root, textvariable=text_entered)
document_type.place(x=int(width)-135,y=int(height)-33, width=40)

convert = Button(root,command=copy_paste,text="GO!")
convert.place(x=int(width)-80,y=int(height)-35, width=70)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `refresh` function why can you not just recalculate the `file_count` variable?  I suspect you'll need to refresh some of the other variables as well though. Something like this maybe:

```
def refresh():
    global path,dirs,files,file_count,dirList
    path, dirs, files = os.walk(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'Input')).next()
    file_count = len(files)
    dirList = os.listdir(path)
```

To get your label to refresh you'll need to do more though. According to the [Tkinter documentation on effbot.org](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/label.htm):

> You can associate a Tkinter variable with a label. When the contents of the variable changes, the label is automatically updated:

For that to work you would need to setup your label differently.

```
file_count_string = StringVar()
counter = Label(textvariable=file_count_string)
counter.pack()
file_count_string.set("Input Directory: " + str(file_count) + " files.")
```

And again when you want to refresh that label:

```
file_count_string.set("Input Directory: " + str(file_count) + " files.")
```

Comment: I like your thinking, nice and simple. I tried this, and a few other things like it but with no luck. I think it has something to do with tKinter (the GUI module) adding the label as a static object, therefore not allowing it's data to be dynamically changed. I have no documentation to back this up, just a hunch. (One way to check this, which I am trying now, is to see if a similar thing works just printing it to the console). Anyway, thanks for the input

Comment: Added some information to my answer on how to refresh your labels.

Comment: Brilliant find man, just goes to show you should always read the 'read me'. I'm on my way home now. When I get there I will try this

Comment: Hey man, I had a bit of a play around with the suggestions you gave me, but couldn't get them to work. The code looks fine, I'm just having trouble with having multiple StringVar()'s I think. As I said I'm self taught so I have gaps in my knowledge. But thanks so much for your help, you've given me more than enough to go on and research how to get it working.